# How to zoom to any feature of Openlayers3 (v3.17.1) map

Tags: openlayers-3

I know this question was discussed at many other topics. But I still not able to find a solution for my issue. None of receipts are works for me.

An issue is very simple. I have a features at my Openlayers3 (v3.17.1) map. I should be able to zoom to any of feature I want.

Before zoom:

[image]

After zoom:

[image]

As I mentioned I use version v3.17.1.

```
var features = myLayer.getSource().getFeatures();
var myFirstFeature = features[0];
```

Option 1:

```
map.zoomToExtent(feature.geometry.getBounds());
```

Option 2:

```
    var bounds = f.geometry.getBounds().clone();
    this._map.zoomToExtent(bounds,false);
```

Comment: Can you show us your code that isn't working and what you tried exactly ?

Comment: updated an original description

Answer (score 11, accepted):

there are many ways to do this, for example if you want to zoom to only one feature and you want to define the level of zoom you can use this :

```
var ext=feature.getGeometry().getExtent();
var center=ol.extent.getCenter(ext);
map.setView( new ol.View({
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',//or any projection you are using
    center: [center[0] , center[1]],//zoom to the center of your feature
    zoom: 12 //here you define the levelof zoom
}));
```

there is another way in which you can zoom to more that just one feature :

```
map.getView().fit(extent, map.getSize());
```

assuming that in extent you have the extent of your feature or features